# handle exclusive parameter java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, parameters, request, handle

My html page sends only **one** parameter. I need to handle it and send a response. This code handles more than one parameter and in my case is not so good:

```
 Enumeration<?> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
        while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = (String) paramNames.nextElement();
        }
```

But how I can modify this code if I have only **one parameter and do not know its name**.
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just add a "do while" loop with an untrue condition in while! or add a count flag to keep track that you have only iterated the above loop only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
Map<String,String[]> paramMap = request.getParameterMap();

    String  myValue = paramMap.get(paramMap.keySet().iterator().next())[0];
```